# Cycles artifacts

Tags: rendering, animation, gpu

There are artifacts visible on my render. Have you any idea?

My configuration :
Windows 7 64 bits
Memory : 12 go

Blender 2.72-27b58f0-win64

2 x GTX Titan Black
Driver : 344.75

[image]

RESOLVED ! Origin this problem is don't plug entry normal map in the shader

Comment: Welcome to blender.SE!  Your problem looks like [z-fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) to me.  But without more details, like some viewport screenshots or a .blend file uploaded to a site like [pastall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/), it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks ! No double visible. I have a similar problem with cpu : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4721466/Cycles/Artifacts.png

Comment: @LukeNukem Could you please elaborate - maybe adding a screen? You forgot to plug the normal map to the output, right?

Comment: This is a complex shader, i forgot plug normal map to the input.